# About RSA+AES encryption (how to decrypt AES in PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, aes, rsa

Today I tried to encrypt and transfer the user-submitted password through the RSA+AES method. I have already completed the preparation of the front-end JS (the code is as follows, and the result of the operation is the same, AES, the value of the RSA encryption will be changed), it uses The two libraries, [jsencrypt](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt) and [crypto-js](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js), are now writing PHP for backend decryption (the code is as follows), but I have encountered some difficulties in this process. The RSA decryption part has been written and tested correctly, but I I don't know how to write the AES decryption part. Even though I have consulted a lot of materials, their examples are different from me. I don't know how to use it (I will attach some examples at the end of the article).
**problem:**
1. Is my JS encryption part correct and logical?
2, how should I write PHP AES decryption part;
3. *Is my idea correct?* :
Client (JavaScript):
AES encryption original user password
RSA public key encryption AES key
---data transmission---
Server (PHP):
RSA private key decryption Get AES key
AES decryption Get the original user password
Obtain the encrypted user password by encrypting the original user password and store it in the database.
**My JavaScript code：**

```js
$(function () {
            //Encrypted part
            //AES
            var password_form="QAQ";
            console.log(password_form);
            var password = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password_form,'Lime Website').toString();
            console.log(password);
            //RSA
            var public_key = $("#inputPublic_key").val();
            console.log(public_key);
            var private_key = $("#inputPrivate_key").val();
            console.log(private_key);
            var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
            encrypt.setPublicKey(public_key);
            var AES_key = encrypt.encrypt(password);
            console.log(AES_key);
        });

        //Decryption part (actually should be done by the server, here for convenience)
        //RSA
        var decrypt = new JSEncrypt();
        decrypt.setPrivateKey(private_key);
        var AES_key_decrypt = decrypt.decrypt(AES_key);
        console.log(AES_key_decrypt);
        //AES
        var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(AES_key_decrypt,'Lime Website');
        var password_decrypt = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        console.log(password_decrypt);
```

**My PHP code:**

```html
<?php
$private_key = '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----';
$private_key_public_key_availability = openssl_pkey_get_private($private_key);//这个函数可用来判断私钥是否是可用的，可用返回资源id Resource id
$AES_key = "iOks+yhKxQBiqtd5rHQRNdXOGqixhNzquuZuPZ5dDsYfh1nDTLiygukiyexNBqHfmA7zis1nRTZW2Nw4bN5Pr2yCgvh1GPV6K5WigO5jD1+ztuyp1hV5ymNSws6EUPPjW9cwrOpO7EIeiYjvGo7ziyPwsCU0vwtQAkNAFY3uhB0=";
$AES_key_decrypted = ""; 
echo "After decrypting the data:";
openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($AES_key),$AES_key_decrypted,$private_key_public_key_availability);
echo $AES_key_decrypted;
```

**Screenshot of one of the JavaScript running results：**
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqxxy.png)
**Some examples:**
https://odan.github.io/2017/08/10/aes-256-encryption-and-decryption-in-php-and-csharp.html
[AES - Crypto JS & PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27452342/aes-crypto-js-php)
[Java encrypt AES, PHP decrypt AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063250/java-encrypt-aes-php-decrypt-aes)
*Finally, sorry for my bad English.*

Comment: Did you check this: https://gist.github.com/turret-io/957e82d44fd6f4493533

Comment: I don't really know what to write in iv, because the crypto-js example does not seem to mention it (sorry)@TahaPaksu

Comment: IV is the initialization vector, you can use whatever you like on that, but you have to use the same both on the encrypter and decrypter.

Comment: Hey... maybe you can give me an example of crypto-js? Thank you @TahaPaksu

Comment: look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/lsloan/4zb9hrxb/

Comment: and here's a tutorial : http://blog.chudinov.net/how-to-encrypt-data-in-browser-with-javascript-and-decrypt-on-server-side-with-php/

Comment: Ok, I may have understood some, but there are still some problems. What is the purpose of the padString function in https://jsfiddle.net/lsloan/4zb9hrxb/? Can key and iv be arbitrary strings? Is there anything that can automatically generate random keys and iv? What is the difference between Encrypted and Encrypted text? Sorry, I may have some stupidity.@TahaPaksu

Comment: No not stupidity, everyone passed these ways to learn something. Padding is something that you use when your data is not filling the block for example 256 bytes in SHA_256 or 512 bytes in SHA_512 type encryption. For example your data is 220 bytes long and you want a SHA256 encryption, you need to pad your data with 36 bytes to get a 256 byte block. Using byte arrays instead of strings in IV and Key may strenghten your encryption. Encrypted data and encrypted text are the same.

Comment: Ok, I have understood the meaning of this JavaScript, I am now trying to write PHP.

Comment: Uh... what happened during the process of encrypted becoming encrypted.ciphertext, which one should I put into PHP to decrypt?@TahaPaksu